# Geopackage trigger doesn't work

Tags: qgis, geopackage, trigger

I use this trigger on a geopackage table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_iae_surf AFTER UPDATE ON "IAE CRD Surf" 
BEGIN 
UPDATE "IAE CRD Surf" SET 
"taille" = ROUND(ST_Area(NEW.geom)/10000,3)
WHERE fid = NEW.fid; 
END
```

When I modify this table in QGIS, I've got this message:
*Erreur OGR lors du paramétrage de l'entité 2802 : failed to execute update : too many levels of trigger recursion*.
I don't find any problem in my trigger. What is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Read https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/52346 and try if this works also for you:

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_iae_surf AFTER UPDATE of dummy ON "IAE CRD Surf" 
BEGIN 
UPDATE "IAE CRD Surf" SET 
"taille" = ROUND(ST_Area(NEW.geom)/10000,3)
WHERE fid = NEW.fid; 
END
```

Comment: Ok, it works for AFTER UPDATE, but how to solve the same problem with AFTER INSERT ?

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger reads:

When table "IAE CRD Surf" is updated then update field "taille" = ROUND(ST_Area(NEW.geom)/10000,3).

This means that when the trigger runs, the trigger will run again because it is updated again.

Probably want:

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_iae_surf AFTER INSERT
ON "IAE CRD Surf" 
BEGIN 
UPDATE "IAE CRD Surf" SET 
"taille" = ROUND(ST_Area(NEW.geom)/10000,3)
WHERE fid = NEW.fid; 
END
```